# How to use facebook social plugins for flutter app?

Tags: flutter, facebook, flutter-plugin, flutter-facebook-social-plugins

I have some use-cases related to [Facebook social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) . Basically, these all plugins from Facebook are for web development. But I need these for my flutter apps. Three of the use-cases are -

**Use-Case 1:** I want to reward some points to my users if they invite others to link my app's Facebook page.

**Use-Case 2:** I want to reward some points to my users if they like my app's Facebook page.

**Use-Case 3:** I want to reward some points to my users if they share their score with screenshots taken by the app automatically to their News feeds. *(Although I got some plugins for this but they didn't look handy to me as there are no success callbacks to prevent spam that if the user really shared the score with a screenshot. I also observed that these plugins only share captions or screenshots at a time but not togetherly)*

Comment: You are not allowed to reward people for these kind of actions to begin with. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-developer-policy-3.2

Comment: @CBroe Do you have any idea which kind of rewarding are valid for facebook policies ? Thank you.

Comment: The ones mentioned on the site I linked to.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems helpful and maybe I need to reconstruct my rewarding processes based on this. @CBroe